# php cookies and session issues when open more tabs for put session expire alert before 60 seconds through jquery

Tags: php, session, cookies

I am using below code in config file

```
if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 600)) {

    session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time 
    session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
}  

$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time();
```

The above code works after 10 min inactive and session will destroy

When user logged in will set cookies like

```
setcookie("loggedin", "true", time()+600);
```

In jquery, I set session time : 600 sec

```
set warning alert set using jquery : 60 seconds[60 seconds before expire session show alert 60]
```

(Your session will expire in 60 seconds!, possible to restart session[Page refresh])

It works fine for opening one tab.  If open second tab page refresh session and cookies reset, start from 600 seconds. but previous tab continues on below 600 seconds the warning alert become early.
(Actullay page refresh only reset cookies and session. but prev tab we can't refersh)
how to fix that issues.

Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before displaying the warning make an AJAX request to verify the last activity, if there is more than 60 seconds left then delay the alert.

Very basic example code below.

time_left.php:

```
session_start();
echo time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] - 600;
```

jQuery:

```
$.ajax('time_left.php').done(function(t) {
   if (t <= 60) {
      // 60 seconds or less left
   }
   else {
      // more than 60 seconds left, reset timer for (t - 60) seconds
   }
});
```

Comment: it's work. but it's possible to alert session expire warning all the tabs at same time with out using setInterval() function.

Comment: I don't understand the question, you need to use setInterval to set code to run after a certain amount of time.